# Prevent anonymous access to /script/admin folder in MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my /scripts folder, I have an "admin" subfolder (/scripts/admin).

How can I prevent anonymous access to this folder? I need only logged in admins to have access to this folder/files (and its subfolders).

I've tried this in web.config, but it doesn't work...

```
<location path="scripts/admin" allowOverride="false">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
       <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a good idea but you could try the following

- move the content of your scripts/admin to App_Data, content of this
  folder will never gets served by the web server.
- create a new controller with just the one action method that accepts
  a filename argument and returns the file with the matching name from
  the App_data folder
- make sure this controller can only be accessible by an admin using
  the Authorize attribute.